# Html Agility Pack returns "The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel", but only on this specific url

Tags: c#, ssl, html-agility-pack

I want to scrape some stuff from this website "https://support.nedap-healthcare.com/topic/datamodellen-onsdb/", but I keep getting the secure channel error. I'm able to scrape other https sites, but only this one is keep getting back at me.

Things I tried thusfar

- ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
- Implemented the GetAllcertifications-method ()
- ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate { return true; };\
- LoadFromBrowser - method

Code:

```
url = @"https://support.nedap-healthcare.com/topic/datamodellen-onsdb/";
element = @"/html/body/div[2]/div/section[3]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/div/ul";

HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
var doc = web.Load(url);
var HeaderNames = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(element);
```

Suggestions and/or help is much apprectiated

**System.Net.Trace - log:**

```
System.Net Information: 0 : [26544] Current OS installation type is 'Server'.
System.Net Verbose: 0 : [26544] Entering WebRequest::Create(https://support.nedap-healthcare.com/topic/datamodellen-onsdb/)
System.Net Verbose: 0 : [26544] Entering HttpWebRequest#45004109::HttpWebRequest(https://support.nedap-healthcare.com/topic/datamodellen-onsdb/#1804052459)
System.Net Information: 0 : [26544] RAS supported: True
System.Net Verbose: 0 : [26544] Exiting HttpWebRequest#45004109::HttpWebRequest() 
System.Net Verbose: 0 : [26544] Exiting WebRequest::Create()    -> HttpWebRequest#45004109
System.Net Verbose: 0 : [26544] Entering HttpWebRequest#45004109::GetResponse()
System.Net Verbose: 0 : [26544] Entering ServicePoint#21454193::ServicePoint(support.nedap-healthcare.com:443)
System.Net Information: 0 : [26544] Associating HttpWebRequest#45004109 with ServicePoint#21454193
System.Net Information: 0 : [26544] Associating Connection#58870012 with HttpWebRequest#45004109
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [26544] Entering Socket#60068066::Socket(AddressFamily#2)
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [26544] Exiting Socket#60068066::Socket() 
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [26544] Entering Socket#3741682::Socket(AddressFamily#23)
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [26544] Exiting Socket#3741682::Socket() 
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [26544] Entering DNS::TryInternalResolve(support.nedap-healthcare.com)
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [26544] Entering Socket#60068066::Connect(217.19.232.19:443#333976162)
System.Net.Sockets Information: 0 : [26544] Socket#60068066 - Created connection from 192.168.15.95:55332 to 217.19.232.19:443.
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [26544] Exiting Socket#60068066::Connect() 
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [26544] Entering Socket#3741682::Close()
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [26544] Entering Socket#3741682::Dispose()
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [26544] Exiting Socket#3741682::Close() 
System.Net Information: 0 : [26544] Connection#58870012 - Created connection from 192.168.15.95:55332 to 217.19.232.19:443.
System.Net Information: 0 : [26544] TlsStream#33675143::.ctor(host=support.nedap-healthcare.com, #certs=0, checkCertificateRevocationList=False, sslProtocols=Tls, Tls11, Tls12)
System.Net Information: 0 : [26544] Associating HttpWebRequest#45004109 with ConnectStream#34640832
System.Net Information: 0 : [26544] HttpWebRequest#45004109 - Request: GET /topic/datamodellen-onsdb/ HTTP/1.1

System.Net Information: 0 : [26544] ConnectStream#34640832 - Sending headers
{
Host: support.nedap-healthcare.com
Connection: Keep-Alive
}.
System.Net Information: 0 : [26544] SecureChannel#43332040::.ctor(hostname=support.nedap-healthcare.com, #clientCertificates=0, encryptionPolicy=RequireEncryption)
System.Net Information: 0 : [26544] Enumerating security packages:
System.Net Information: 0 : [26544]     Negotiate
System.Net Information: 0 : [26544]     NegoExtender
System.Net Information: 0 : [26544]     Kerberos
System.Net Information: 0 : [26544]     NTLM
System.Net Information: 0 : [26544]     TSSSP
System.Net Information: 0 : [26544]     pku2u
System.Net Information: 0 : [26544]     WDigest
System.Net Information: 0 : [26544]     Schannel
System.Net Information: 0 : [26544]     Microsoft Unified Security Protocol Provider
System.Net Information: 0 : [26544]     CREDSSP
System.Net Information: 0 : [26544] SecureChannel#43332040 - Left with 0 client certificates to choose from.
System.Net Information: 0 : [26544] SecureChannel#43332040::.AcquireClientCredentials, new SecureCredential() (flags=(ValidateManual, NoDefaultCred, SendAuxRecord), m_ProtocolFlags=(Tls10Client, Tls11Client, Tls12Client), m_EncryptionPolicy=RequireEncryption)
System.Net Information: 0 : [26544] AcquireCredentialsHandle(package = Microsoft Unified Security Protocol Provider, intent  = Outbound, scc     = System.Net.SecureCredential)
System.Net Information: 0 : [26544] InitializeSecurityContext(credential = System.Net.SafeFreeCredential_SECURITY, context = (null), targetName = support.nedap-healthcare.com, inFlags = ReplayDetect, SequenceDetect, Confidentiality, AllocateMemory, InitManualCredValidation)
System.Net Information: 0 : [26544] InitializeSecurityContext(In-Buffer length=0, Out-Buffer length=196, returned code=ContinueNeeded).
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [26544] Entering Socket#60068066::Send()
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [26544] Data from Socket#60068066::Send
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [26544] 00000000 : 16 03 03 00 BF 01 00 00-BB 03 03 60 F0 94 39 06 : ...........`..9.
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [26544] 00000010 : 94 E5 4B FD 42 3D E8 4B-A8 8A EC E1 15 9A 52 09 : ..K.B=.K......R.
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [26544] 00000020 : F7 78 48 3A 74 C0 2D 52-0F 33 9B 00 00 38 C0 28 : .xH:t.-R.3...8.(
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [26544] 00000030 : C0 27 C0 14 C0 13 00 9F-00 9E 00 39 00 33 00 9D : .'.........9.3..
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [26544] 00000040 : 00 9C 00 3D 00 3C 00 35-00 2F C0 2C C0 2B C0 24 : ...=.<.5./.,.+.$
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [26544] 00000050 : C0 23 C0 0A C0 09 00 6A-00 40 00 38 00 32 00 0A : .#.....j.@.8.2..
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [26544] 00000060 : 00 13 00 05 00 04 01 00-00 5A 00 00 00 21 00 1F : .........Z...!..
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [26544] 00000070 : 00 00 1C 73 75 70 70 6F-72 74 2E 6E 65 64 61 70 : ...support.nedap
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [26544] 00000080 : 2D 68 65 61 6C 74 68 63-61 72 65 2E 63 6F 6D 00 : -healthcare.com.
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [26544] 00000090 : 0A 00 06 00 04 00 17 00-18 00 0B 00 02 01 00 00 : ................
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [26544] 000000A0 : 0D 00 14 00 12 06 01 06-03 04 01 05 01 02 01 04 : ................
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [26544] 000000B0 : 03 05 03 02 03 02 02 00-23 00 00 00 17 00 00 FF : ........#.......
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [26544] 000000C0 : 01 00 01 00                                     : ....
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [26544] Exiting Socket#60068066::Send()     -> Int32#196
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [26544] Entering Socket#60068066::Receive()
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [26544] Data from Socket#60068066::Receive
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [26544] 00000000 : 15 03 03 00 02                                  : .....
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [26544] Exiting Socket#60068066::Receive()  -> Int32#5
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [26544] Entering Socket#60068066::Receive()
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [26544] Data from Socket#60068066::Receive
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [26544] 00000005 : 02 28                                           : .(
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [26544] Exiting Socket#60068066::Receive()  -> Int32#2
System.Net Information: 0 : [26544] InitializeSecurityContext(credential = System.Net.SafeFreeCredential_SECURITY, context = 77c0c6a6f0:48dea9540, targetName = support.nedap-healthcare.com, inFlags = ReplayDetect, SequenceDetect, Confidentiality, AllocateMemory, InitManualCredValidation)
System.Net Information: 0 : [26544] InitializeSecurityContext(In-Buffers count=2, Out-Buffer length=0, returned code=IllegalMessage).
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [26544] Entering Socket#60068066::Dispose()
System.Net Error: 0 : [26544] Exception in HttpWebRequest#45004109:: - The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel..
System.Net Error: 0 : [26544] Exception in HttpWebRequest#45004109::GetResponse - The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel..
System.Net Error: 0 : [26544] Exception in AppDomain#54444047::UnhandledExceptionHandler - The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel..
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
```

[Screenshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ASRMp.png)

Comment: I have updated answer.

Comment: It looks like the server is asking you to supply a client certificate to create a mutually trusted connection. From what I can see you're not providing a client certificate when setting up the connection. https://dotnetfiddle.net/Mobile?id=lT8Qzo#code-editor

Comment: There is an event on the HtmlWeb object to add the Client certificates to the request without having to manage your own we request creation. `web.PreRequest += request =>
{
...
};`

Answer (score 0):

Can you check your system date-time or proxy settings.
I just pasted your code and it seems working fine for me.

[image]

or add some more error information in your question.

EDIT :

You can create own web requester to get HTML page.

```
//The cookies will be here.
        private CookieContainer _cookies = new CookieContainer();

        //In case you need to clear the cookies
        public void ClearCookies()
        {
            _cookies = new CookieContainer();
        }
        public HtmlDocument GetHtmlPage(string url)
        {
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            request.Method = "GET";
            request.Timeout = 10000;
            //Set more parameters here...
            //...

            //This is the important part.
            request.CookieContainer = _cookies;

            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            var stream = response.GetResponseStream();

            //When you get the response from the website, the cookies will be stored
            //automatically in "_cookies".

            using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
            {
                string html = reader.ReadToEnd();
                var doc = new HtmlDocument();
                doc.LoadHtml(html);

                return doc;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Tried to supply you with as much info as possible.
Weird that the code works on your side & thanks for testing it!
other url's work just fine, so proxy is not necessary.
datet-time settings on system is ok

Comment: sadly, same error at "HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();"
System.Net.WebException: 'The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.'

Opening the link in a browser works just fine.